# Why my bindable picker doesn't work?

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, xamarin.forms, picker

here is my code behind

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> cidadeItems
    {
        get { return cditems; }
        set
        {
            cditems = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(String)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void PopulaPickerCidade(string estadoSelecionado)
    {
        cidadeList = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        bool repetido; //repetido = thesame
        foreach (var itemLojaLst in lstLoja)
        {
            repetido = false;
            if (estadoSelecionado.ToUpper().Equals(itemLojaLst.estado.ToUpper()))
            {
                if (cidadeList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var itemCidLst in cidadeList)
                    {
                        if (itemCidLst.Equals(itemLojaLst.cidade))
                        {
                            repetido = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!repetido)
                    cidadeList.Add(itemLojaLst.cidade);
            }
        }

       // cidadeList.Sort();

        cidadeItems = cidadeList;
    }
```

I saw the program calling this methods and it seems work...my list is receiving normal in the way I wanted... But, The xaml (My picker) doesn't show the data in the picker...the second method is called when I press a button and fill my Observable that should fill the picker.

This is my xaml:

```
<Picker x:Name="cidadepicker" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding cidadeItems}" 
        Title="Cidade" 
        SelectedIndexChanged="PickerCidade_SelectedindexChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check how you set BindingContext on page. Then try instead of

```
new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(String))
```

call

```
new PropertyChangedEventArgs("cidadeItems")
```

Comment: what is the difference between BindingContext="{Binding cidadeItems}"  and ItemsSource="{Binding cidadeItems}"?

Comment: some elements have ItemsSource like listview, some don't. Did the answer work for you?

Comment: no, I think I am doing something wrong and I can't see